# Showing many-to-many fields in template

Tags: django

I have this situation :

Models:-

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-name"]

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='author_headshots')


    def __str__(self):             
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author') 
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_authors(self):
        return "\n".join([a.name for a in self.authors.all()])
```

I want to show authors field in template with Publishers

Template:

```
{% for a in obj.pk|get_author %}
    {{ a.name }}<br/>
    {{ a.headshot }}
{% endfor %}
```

Custom Template Tags:

```
def get_author(pk):
    try:
        publisher = Publisher.objects.get(pk=pk)
        print type(publisher)
        author = Author.objects.filter(Publisher=publisher)
        print author
    except:
        author = []
    return author

register.filter('get_author', get_author)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is completely pointless. To iterate over the authors for a publisher, you can just do `{% for author in obj.author_set.all %}` (assuming `obj` is a Publisher object, which you haven't shown).

There doesn't seem to be anything to do with many-to-many relationships here though.